# How to stop reading a text when it gets to a string? Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file that I have to read from that looks like this:

```
n 8.8 45.5
n 6.6 63
n 5.1 88.25
p low 200
```

Here is my code:

```
file_name = input(("Enter name of file: "))
txt = open(file_name, "r")
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split(" ")
    duration = float(fields[2])
    miles = float(fields[1])
    name = fields[0]
    if name == "n" and miles != "low":
        print(running.to_string())
    else:
        print("hello")
```

Every time I run this code I get the following error:

```
miles = float(fields[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'l'
```

I initially thought that if I made an "if" statement saying that as long as the value read "n" it would stop before it got to "p" and therefore it wouldn't matter if the last part was a string rather than an int or float. After that didn't work, I added the "miles != 'low'" hoping that would fix it but it didn't. If anyone can help me find a way for the file to stop once it gets to the last "n" so that it does not get to the part that says "low" It would really help me out.

Comment: Your code never assigns anything to `workout_type`.

Comment: Use `name` instead of `workout_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a string "low" to a float. This is occurring on the line:

```
miles = float(fields[1])
```

So adding a check AFTER that point won't help you. Try this:

```
file_name = input(("Enter name of file: "))
txt = open(file_name, "r")
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split(" ")
    duration = float(fields[2])
    if fields[1] != 'low':
        miles = float(fields[1])
    name = fields[0]
    if workout_type == "n":
        print(running.to_string())
    else:
        print("hello")
```

As others have mentioned, the code snippet you provided won't run as-is because there are some unassigned names. But this should give you the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the last line of your text file, you are trying to convert a string ('low') to a float. For this, you need to do an if or a try statement to ensure that the second column is actually a float.

```
try:
    miles = float(fields[1])
except ValueError:
    # The second column is not a float.
```

Secondly, according to your error, the string 'low' has actually been parsed into its individual letters. For example, your fields list may look like this:

```
fields = ['p', 'l', 'o', 'w', ...]
```

I can't know this for sure, but it looks like you arent splitting that line properly. Maybe there is an extra space in there somewhere? Regardless, the error clearly tells you that the second element of your fields list is the string 'l', not 'low' like you would expect. Do some debugging and see why that is.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_name = input(('Enter name of file: '))
txt = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in txt:
    fields = line.strip().split(' ')
    duration = float(fields[2])
    miles = float(fields[1]) if not fields[1].isalpha() else fields[1]
    name = fields[0]
    if name == 'n' and miles != 'low':
        print(running.to_string())
    else:
        print('hello')
```

Comment: Notice the error says fields[1] = 'l'. Given your answer, miles will be set to 'l', instead of 'low', thus the condition will be met even though it shouldn't be.